# PyCharm Python ImportError Behave

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-behave

I'm trying to run some tests in PyCharm using Behave and it keeps telling me I have this issue:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/behave", line 7, in <module>
    from behave.__main__ import main
ImportError: No module named behave.__main__
```

I had a colleague clone the project and they can run it fine on their machine, any insights?

Python 2.7.10

```
$ pip freeze | grep ehave 
behave==1.2.5
```

Comment: What is your behave version? Run ``pip freeze | grep ehave`` and add output here

Comment: @user996142 thanks added that in

Comment: Does it work from terminal? Can you simply run ``behave``?

Comment: @user996142 yes, it works from terminal, i found my issue, i'll post it as the answer, thanks for looking into this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that in Project Interpreter, I was using a different version of Python on my machine that did not have behave installed/included.

Answer (score 0):

From Pycharm settings -> Project -> Python interpreter , search for behave and include it into your ptoject.